# Can't downgrade Android Gradle plugin version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

What could be the reason I can't downgrade Android Gradle plugin version?

I have updated to `Gradle plugin 2.0` and now I want to use 1.5 but my installed Android Studio says :

```
> Error:The project is using an incompatible version of the Android
> Gradle plugin. Please update your project to use version 2.1.0

 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

ad requested in Google Analytics latest version , but the Gradle not working as i want so i want to return to 1.5 .

this is my Gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use stable version of google play APIs ie, `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'` with latest **Gradle Plugin**.

Comment: i don't want the latest Gradle plugin . i found some issues in this version i don't like .

Comment: It's a pity that AS is not more tolerant on this. In a larger team everyone is forced to upgrade if the project uses the new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

instead

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

and in the inner Gradle file :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

instead

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Solved the problem .

all i need to check now is the affect on the Google Analyticts but the code compiled and run so at least we know for sure what is the incompatible part .